# ionic windows phone 8.1 ion-scroll zoom doesn't work

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ionic-framework, zooming

I'm creating an app in Ionic which should have a zoomable content part (with pinch to zoom). I have the following  element:

```
<ion-scroll zooming="true" direction="xy" min-zoom="1" scrollbar-x="false" scrollbar-y="false"> ... </ion-scroll>
```

This works for iOS and Android, but on Windows Phone 8.1 the content does not zoom. It just scrolls the element a bit and moves back to original state.

I know Windows Phone is not supported completely by Ionic, but I hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong or someone has another solution for content zooming.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do these CSS styles help? `overflow: scroll;
    -ms-content-zooming: zoom !important;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-max: 1000%;
    -ms-content-zoom-limit-min: 5%;`

Comment: BTW is this supported for Windows 10 in Ionic2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these `CSS` styles:

```
overflow                   : scroll; 
-ms-content-zooming        : zoom !important; 
-ms-content-zoom-limit-max : 1000%; 
-ms-content-zoom-limit-min : 5%;
```

Comment: At this moment, I'm not working on this project anymore. I will test it when I'm working on the project :). Thanks anyway!